# How to set system mouse double click speed

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I am building a Dotnet Core 3.1 Console application where i want to get and set system's mouse double click speed.

[image]

I got success to get the speed using

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int GetDoubleClickTime();
```

But not able to set desired values for the same.

I have tried following options but did not get success

1. SetDoubleClickTime

- current system values is 550 received from above method
- Passing 200 as Arg1 value to modify.
- received output of below method as true but value did not change

Implementation:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
     static extern bool SetDoubleClickTime(uint Arg1);
```

2. SystemParametersInfo

- I have also tried with SystemParametersInfo
- received output of below method as true but value did not change

Implementation:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr ipParam, int fWinIni);

 var result= SystemParametersInfo(20, 200, IntPtr.Zero, 2);
```

Comment: Just a sidenote; there are some limitations on the clock of the OS so some small values may not work

Comment: I have tried with multiple values between 500 -5000 but did not get reflection for any of them

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me even for values as low as 100ms. Did you try to `GetDoubleClickTime()` after setting it to check whether your value was actually set?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetDoubleClickTime();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetDoubleClickTime(uint Arg1);

    public static void Main()
    {
        var time = GetDoubleClickTime();
        Console.WriteLine(time);
        SetDoubleClickTime(4200);
        time = GetDoubleClickTime();
        Console.WriteLine(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. But this is not working properly. you will get applied changes by calling GetDoubleClickTime just after SetDoubleClickTime. But same value will not get applied to mose setting page a i have shown in an image. And when you will start your console again then you will realize that setting not applied.

Comment: The user32.dll way of changing settings is a quick hack to do it without logging off 
 and rebooting. The actual values are stored in the registry under "HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse" so you need to modify the DoubleClickSpeed key for persistence. That's where the mouse setting page takes the values from.

Comment: I know the way to change through registry. But i was planing to ignore direct registry modification. But now i believe i will have to go with that. Thank you!